# bootstrap 3 datetimepicker((eonasdan)) - e.date is undefined on "dp.show"

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker

I am using the [eonasdan bootstrap 3 datepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) (v4.14.30).
I try to read ***e.date*** value on ***dp.show*** and I get ***undefined***.
Has anyone had a similar problem?
Here is a jsfiddle of the issue.
        https://jsfiddle.net/adollphus/c79ddtok/

Thanks for your time.

Html

```
<div class="input-group date" style="max-width: 300px; float:left;">
    <input class="form-control model-edit-info input-sm"
    id="datepicker"
    type="text" />
    <span class="input-group-addon input-sm" style="cursor:pointer">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var datepicker = $('#datepicker').parent();
    datepicker.datetimepicker({
        locale: 'pl',
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
        minDate: new Date(1900, 0, 1),
        showTodayButton: true,
        toolbarPlacement: 'top',
        widgetPositioning: {
            horizontal: 'right'
        }
    });
    datepicker.on('dp.show', function (e) {
        alert('e.date=' + e.date);
    });
});
```

Comment: try dp.change. here's the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/c79ddtok/5/

Comment: Yes, it works. I think this is sufficient for my needs. Thanks.

Comment: let me post it as a solution. please upvote it and mark it as an answer if it works for you.

Comment: I guess I don't have enough reputation points to upvote your answer. I can only mark it as a solution.

Comment: no problem. thanks for marking it as a solution. glad was able to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `dp.show` with `dp.change`

```
datepicker.on('dp.show', function(e) {
    alert('e.date=' + e.date);
});
```

with

```
datepicker.on('dp.change', function(e) {
    alert('e.date=' + e.date);
});
```

here's the updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c79ddtok/5/)